# Pandas print unique values as string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a list of unique value from selected column in pandas dataframe. What I want to achieve is to print the result as string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','C','C','B','A','C','B']})
a = df['A'].unique()

print(a)

Output: ['A' 'C' 'B']

Desired output: A, C, B
```

So far I've tried below,

```
print(a.to_string())
Got this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_string'

print(a.tostring())
Got this: b'\xf0\x04\xa6P\x9e\x01\x00\x000\xaf\x92P\x9e\x01\x00\x00\xb0\xaf\x92P\x9e\x01\x00\x00'
```

Can anyone give a hint.

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','C','C','B','A','C','B']})
a = df['A'].unique()

print(', '.join(a))  # or print(*a, sep=', ')
```

Prints:

```
A, C, B
```

---

EDIT: To store as variable:

```
text = ', '.join(a)
print(text)
```

Comment: Thx! What if I want to store the output as variable. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

py3 solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A','C','C','B','A','C','B']})
a = df['A'].unique()

print(*a,  sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
print(', '.join(a))
```